# how can i generate code with char and int?

Tags: java

```
String movieid;
String Random;
while (true) {
        Random random = new Random();

        
        char randomizedCharacter = (char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'A');
        char randomizedCharacter1 = (char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'A');

        Integer x = (int)(Math.random() * (9-1)) + 1;
        Integer y = (int)(Math.random() * (9-0));
        Integer y2 = (int)(Math.random() * (9-0));
        
        movieid = randomizedCharacter + randomizedCharacter1 + x.toString() + y.toString() + y2.toString();
        
        
         System.out.println("Generated MovieID: " +movieid );
         break;
```

i want to generate like some movie id, with format xxyyy x is char and y is integer. When i print the id in println it goes well but if i put it in movieid like in the code, the output is all integer. Can you give advice about mycode.

Comment: One option: `movieid = String.format("%c%c%d%d%d", randomizedCharacter, randomizedCharacter1, x, y, y2);`

Answer (score -1):

You can get a string representation of a character by using:

```
Character.toString(char)
```

Or

```
String.valueOf(char)
```